# NullReferenceException in Custom tag helper in MVc core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

i created a tag helper to support bilingual website. i have two database column for text properties one for Arabic and one for English.Created a CustomTagHelper to switch models columns when changing language.

```
     public class LabelPolyglotTagHelper : TagHelper
{

    public const string LabelPolyglotCultureAttributeName = "polyglot-culture-value";
    public const string LabelPolyglotArabicAttributeName = "polyglot-ar-value";
    public const string LabelPolyglotEnglishAttributeName = "polyglot-en-value";


    [HtmlAttributeName(LabelPolyglotCultureAttributeName)]
    public string CultureValue { get; set; } = "";

    [HtmlAttributeName(LabelPolyglotEnglishAttributeName)]
    public string EnValue { get; set; } = "ar-KW";

    [HtmlAttributeName(LabelPolyglotArabicAttributeName)]
    public string ArValue { get; set; } = "";

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        output.TagName = "label";    // Replaces <email> with <a> tag

        if (CultureValue == "ar-KW")
        {
            output.Content.SetHtmlContent(ArValue);
        }
        else
        {
            output.Content.SetHtmlContent(EnValue);
        }
        base.Process(context, output);
    }

}
```

and in my page i use it with a check box to show Categories

```
    @model IMK.Models.Brand
   @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
    @inject IViewLocalizer Localizer

@{
    var culture = HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Where(x => 
x.Key == "culture").FirstOrDefault().Value;
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutAdmin.cshtml";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

<h4>Brand</h4><div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <form asp-action="Create" >
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.CategoryBrands.Count; i++)
            {
                var role = Model.CategoryBrands[i];
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CategoryBrands[i].CategoryID)

                <input type="checkbox" asp-for="@Model.CategoryBrands[i].Select" />

                <label-polyglot polyglot-ar-value="@Model.CategoryBrands[i].Category.CategoryNameAr"
                polyglot-en-value="@Model.CategoryBrands[i].Category.CategoryNameEn"
                polyglot-culture-value="@culture" ></label-polyglot>

                @*@Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoryBrands[i].Category.CategoryNameEn, role.Category.CategoryNameEn)*@
             <br />
            }

        </div>
```

it can switch language  page but when i submit page it throws null reference exception

Comment: A taghelper only involves rendering HTML to a page. Submitting a form is an entirely separate process that does not involve the taghelper. If you're getting an error there, we need to see the code for your action(s) instead.

Comment: i solved it, problem was i forgot to add text box for Brands Arabic name in View .Sorry for trouble